# Change UITableViewCellAcessory in didSelectRowAtIndexPath function

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Is there any way of changing the `UITableViewCellAccessory` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function?

I need to change a "play"-icon to a "stop"-icon..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a pointer to the table cell in question by using the method

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

and passing the indexPath that is passed in as a parameter to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and then change it's `accessoryView` property. Like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setAccessoryView:stopIconView];
```

Where `stopIconView` is likely to be a UIImageView or something.

Comment: Ok, so I did what you said, but I get an error:

`Request for member 'tableViewThing' in something not a structure or union`

Do you know why?

Comment: Whichever class you tried to access `tableViewThing` on, obviously doesn't have a `tableViewThing` property. What is `tableViewThing`? This should be a separate question if it's not related to the table view cell retrieval

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking at the accessoryView property in [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView) and see if it is possible to add an image to it.